# NixOS - how to add ping command on code-server terminal

Tags: nixos, code-server

Which package should I add to `extraPackages` property to make `ping` command available?
I have tried

`extraPackages = with pkgs; [ ping ];`

But it didnot work, it installs completely different package.

Comment: `ping` needs a setuid wrapper, so you'll have to add `/run/wrappers/bin` to its `PATH` rather than adding a package, as store contents can't have setuid.
Setuid in packages would make Nix not "policy-free", which is core to its design and enables safe user-requested builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean this `ping`, it's in the `iputils` package:

```
bash-5.1# ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
^C
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.075/0.075/0.075/0.000 ms
bash-5.1# which ping
/sbin/ping
bash-5.1# ls -l /sbin/ping 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 69 Jan  1  1980 /sbin/ping -> /nix/store/c8i7qgcvnj3123n8k7yilimgvdl23a31-iputils-20211215/bin/ping
```

Answer (score 0):

`ping` is part of `iputils` so adding this package to `extraPackages` will make it available. You can find an executable with the tool like `nix-locate <bin/executable>` from the package `nix-index`

However keep in mind that `ping` normally requires the SUID bit set.
This tool is available in `/run/wrappers/bin/ping` ( `command -v ping` ). This wrapper is created in `nixos/modules/tasks/network-interfaces.nix`:

```
security.wrappers = {
  ping = {
    owner = "root";
    group = "root";
    capabilities = "cap_net_raw+p";
    source = "${pkgs.iputils.out}/bin/ping";
  };
};
```